# Django - how to retrieve data from two models (at the same time) related with OneToOne relation?

Tags: django, view

In Django I have two models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    model_name = CharField(...)
    make_name = CharField(...)
    car_exterior_color=  = CharField( CHOICES )
    
    
class CarWash(models.Model):
   car_washed = BooleanField(...) 
   wash_date = DateTimeField(...)
   added_wax = BooleanField(...)
   car = models.OneToOneField(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Car washed")
```

I need to show such table in view, that retrieves data from two models:

| model_name | make_name | car_ext_col | car_washed ? | added_wax ? | wash date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IS | Lexus | blue | Yes | No | 2023-02-02 |
| G37 | Infiniti | white | No | No | -- |
| RX | Lexus | red | Yes | No | 2023-02-02 |
| Corolla | Toyota | green | No | No | -- |
| Tundra | Toyota | blue | Yes | Yes | 2023-02-02 |
| Q70 | Infiniti | yellow | Yes | Yes | 2023-02-03 |
| Civic | Honda | black | Yes | No | 2023-02-03 |
| Malibu | Chevrolet | red | Yes | Yes | 2023-02-04 |
| GS | Lexus | yellow | Yes | No | 2023-02-04 |
| Q30 | Infiniti | white | No | No | -- |

What should I write in views.py?

How to retrieve data from two models to get table as above?

Should I change my model to get table as required?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to create separate app to join 2 data models, and inside this app create model which combines your 2 data models, and create view etc for that data model.

Comment: Are you sure? It sounds strange that I need another app to access model's data.

Comment: Finally I solved this problem.